# Sprite Kit collision detection only with left and right screen edges

Tags: ios, collision-detection, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

so I want my Hero to collide with the edges of the screen, but just with the right and the left wall not with the bottom or top.

Until now I have set up this in my `-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size`:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = SceneEdgeCategory;
```

My hero has this in his method:

```
hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SceneEdgeCategory;
```

Everything works great so far, but as the whole screen is a physics body my hero collide with all edges. Any ideas how to let him collide just with the walls?

Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is adding a physics "box" around the whole screen. What you are looking for is two walls on the left and right sides of the screen. This should do the trick:

```
//make sure that you define the topLeftPoint, bottomLeftPoint, topRightPoint and bottomLeftPoint variables 

self.leftPhysicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:topLeftPoint toPoint:bottomLeftPoint];
self.leftPhysicsBody.categoryBitMask = SceneEdgeCategory;

self.rightPhysicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:topRightPoint toPoint:bottomRightPoint];
self.rightPhysicsBody.categoryBitMask = SceneEdgeCategory;
```

Comment: I added leftPhysicsBody and rightPhysicsBody to my property list and added the above to my initWithSize method together with the definition of the points, but it doesn't work out somehow. The points are defined right, I checked that. Is there anything special I need to know about how to setup leftPhysicsBody/rightPhysicsBody?

Comment: Are you sure that you defined all of the points correctly? [Here is a document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html) about the coordinate system used by sprite kit. I think the correct points would be 0,0 (bottom left); 0,1 (top left); 1,0 (bottom right) and 1,1 (top right).

Comment: Were you able to detect contact in -didBeginContact doing this? I'm trying to detect contact between a body and the edge rect i've created around the screen but it simply is not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint topRightPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

That's how mine look, but I checked they work well. I added: `@property (nonatomic) SKPhysicsBody* leftPhysicsBody;
@property (nonatomic) SKPhysicsBody* rightPhysicsBody;` And then there is your part from above in my initWithSize method. Do I maybe somehow add the two physicBodies too my scene? Like I tried to init and alloc them but it didn't help.